# Cannot find activities as shown in AndroidManifest.xml for the Facebook apk file

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, reverse-engineering, apktool

I downloaded an apk file from http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/facebook-107-0-0-0-38-release/. I decompiled it using **Apktool 2.2.1** which was successful. I looked for the launcher activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Here is the code for the launcher activity

```
<activity-alias android:exported="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon_katana" android:name="com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity" android:targetActivity="com.facebook.katana.activity.FbMainTabActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="crash.loop.exclude" android:value="true"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

But i **did not find any LoginActivity.smali or FbMainTabActivity.smali in com/facebook/katana** folder. Moreover in the com/facebook/katana folder there is **only one folder** named **app** which contains only 2 files for the splash activity. Here is a screenshot--
[image]

My question is **why can't I find the smali files as show in the AndroidManifest.xml file**? Is it **due to ProGuard**?

**NOTE:**- ***I have knowledge in developing android apps***.